# Postgres JDBC fetchSize() ignored

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

Why I'm having the fetch size ignored, I set it to 2, but whenever I run the program it returns whole records! If I print the fetch size will print 2, but the result will return whole records. Any implementation that I can return rows according to the fetch size? i.e I have 10 records in my DB I need to return 2 records for each trip in my tableAsStream method?

```
private Stream<SecurityGroup> tableAsStream(Context context, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    try {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.setFetchSize(FETCH_SIZE);
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SELECT_SCHEDULE_MODULES_QUERY);

        log.info("Returning a stream of SecurityGroups from the prepared statement ");
        return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<SecurityGroup>(Long.MAX_VALUE, Spliterator.ORDERED) {
            @Override
            public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super SecurityGroup> action) {
                try {
                    if(!resultSet.next()) return false;
                    action.accept(createRecord(resultSet));
                    return true;
                } catch(SQLException ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            }
        }, false);
    } catch(SQLException sqlEx) {
        throw sqlEx;
    }
}

public void migrate(Context context) throws Exception {
    Connection connection = context.getConnection();

//        do{

    log.info("Migration script started for (SCHEDULE_SHIFTS_EDIT_SELF).");

        List<SecurityGroup> securityGroupList = tableAsStream(context, connection).collect(Collectors.toList());

        securityGroupList.stream()
                         .flatMap(securityGroup -> securityGroup.getModules().stream())
                         .filter(securityModule -> securityModule.getName() == ModuleName.SCHEDULE)
                         .forEach(filteredSecurityModule -> {
                             boolean editPermissionExists = filteredSecurityModule.getFeatures().stream()
                                                                                  .anyMatch(x->PermissionName.SCHEDULE_SHIFTS_EDIT == x.getName());
                             boolean editSelfPermissionExists = filteredSecurityModule.getFeatures().stream()
                                                                                      .anyMatch(x->PermissionName.SCHEDULE_SHIFTS_EDIT_SELF == x.getName());
                             if (editPermissionExists && !editSelfPermissionExists) {
                                 filteredSecurityModule.getFeatures().add(SecurityFeature.of(PermissionName.SCHEDULE_SHIFTS_EDIT_SELF, true, false));
                             }
                         });
        updateSecurityGroups(securityGroupList, context);
        log.info("Migration script Ended for (SCHEDULE_SHIFTS_EDIT_SELF).");

//        } while(condition);
}
```

Comment: You *should* be getting whole records or 'rows' as they are called in SQL. What's your problem with that?

Comment: The fetch size controls the number of (complete) rows that are fetched from the server in one round trip. It neither reduces the total number of rows returned, nor the number of columns returned. If you want to limit the total number of rows, use `setMaxRows()` if you want to return fewer columns, then change your SELECT statement to select fewer columns.

Comment: You don't need to do anything. The driver will take care of that. You still need to call `next()` for each row in the result. It's purely an optimization on the network layer.

Comment: OK got it, yup the next already in my code. 
if(!resultSet.next()) return false;
action.accept(createRecord(resultSet));

Comment: Any implementation that I can return rows according to the fetch size? i.e I have 15 records in my DB I need to return 5 records for each trip in my tableAsStream method?

Comment: The fetch size is only a recommendation to the JDBC driver. The JDBC driver is free to adjust it, as is the server. In any case with such small numbers TCP buffering will obviate whatever you do. Just return 5 rows per call and let the JDBC driver worry about the fetch size. And stop calling them 'records'.